# Amazon RDS low in memory no mysql connections

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm running the free instance of amazon RDS connection to a t2.medium ec2 instace. We are running a wordpress website with 20 active plugins and about 800 pages. I can see that I am low in memory (freeable memory) down to 52MB. There is only 1 database connection active and the google analytics real time report show only 1 visitor which is me.

mysql show process list returns

+---------+----------+---------------------+-------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id | User | Host | db | Command | Time | State | Info |
+---------+----------+---------------------+-------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| ****| ***** | l****:46109 | mysql | Sleep | 4 | | NULL |
| ****| **** | ****:33918 | NULL | Query | 0 | init | show processlist |
+---------+----------+---------------------+-------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

what is consuming my memory?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general server tech support.

Comment: thats normal, dont worry